# allow posting of visitor message by guests to member profiles in vbulletin

Tags: vbulletin

I want to allow posting of visitor message by guests to anyone's profile. Can anyone please help? Is there any query for that?

Answer (score 0):

This option can be set in vbulletin admincp > usergroups > unregistered > visitor messages permissions at the bottom. Set can post visitor message to others profile - I suggest you set follow moderation settings to no so always moderated.

RoyMogg at the www.bizface.co.uk forum